# Set up spf and DKIM for host sent emails and gsuite on Bluehost

Tags: wordpress, spf, dkim, bluehost

I have a Bluehost shared server with an wordpress application.
I also have Google Suite set up to send emails through my domain, which is working fine. 
Now I am trying to set up the wordpress application to send emails but they always end up in Spam. Looking at gmail, it gives me the below information.

SPF:    SOFTFAIL com o IP X.X.X.X 
DKIM:   'FAIL' com o domínio domain.com.br

Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning informativo@domain.com.br does not designate X.X.X.X as permitted sender) client-ip=X.X.X.X;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@domain.com.br header.s=default header.b=I3CqwZBH;
       spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning informativo@domain.com.br does not designate X.X.X.X as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=informativo@domain.com.br
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=domain.com.br; s=default; h=Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type: MIME-Version:Message-ID:Subject:Reply-To:From:To:Date:Sender:Cc:Content-ID: Content-Description:Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender:Resent-To:Resent-Cc :Resent-Message-ID:In-Reply-To:References:List-Id:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe: List-Subscribe:List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive; bh=XXX/XXXX/XXXX=; b=XXXXX XXX/+XXXX/XXX/XXXX/XXXX+XXX/XXXX+XXXX+XXXX+XXX XXX;

My SPF is set as:
v=spf1 +include:_spf.google.com ~all

My DKIM is set as:
google._domainkey   14400   IN  TXT "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=XXXXX/XXX/XXXX+XXXX/XXXXXX"

How do I set up both entries to accept also script sent email from my own domain through the website as well as the GSuite settings?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your bluehost IP to your SPF, since that's where you're sending from. Either find bluehost's own SPF record, or add your literal IP to your SPF record:

```
v=spf1 ip4:x.x.x.x include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

You may find that adding `a` or `mx` clauses may be easier, but the ip4 clause is better (faster for receivers to check) if you have a fixed IP.

Also note you never need to use `+` in SPF records as it's the default designator.

You don't appear to have any DKIM issues.

Comment: Thanks. I added that and it helped a bit. Now emails from the site to the same domain emails work without getting to spam, but to other emails still go to spam. Also, I did have dkim issues, sorry it wasn't pasted above, but it was giving me a temperror . 
It still get a DKIM: 'FAIL' com o domínio domain.com.br

Here is the response:

dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@domain.com.br header.s=default header.b=F1qKMtBF;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of informativo@domain.com.br designates X.X.X.X as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=informativo@domain.com.br

Thanks

Comment: Hi I still have an error with the DKIM, that is why i didn't set your post as answered., Any idea how I can set it?

Comment: The DKIM failure looks like it's because you're signing with the wrong key, or the right key but with the wrong domain, or that you have not put your public keys in your DNS. Any DKIM checker should be able to verify these things.